# Coffeescript joining multiple files using wilcard not working

Tags: windows, coffeescript, cmd, wildcard

I'm new in **coffeescript**, I just play around with this command to join my coffee files:

```
coffee.cmd -cj scriptall.js *.coffee
```

it resulting

```
File not found: C:\xampp\htdocs\foo\js\*.coffee
```

That was weird, because I have **test1.coffee, test2.coffee** and **test3.coffee** on **C:\xampp\htdocs\foo\js\**.
I have to set the target files explicitly like this to make it work:

```
coffee.cmd -cj scriptall.js test1.coffee test2.coffee test3.coffee
```

Anyone knows how to resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like the console you're using does not support wildcards. Which one is it, `cmd`?

Comment: I'm using windows command console, the cmd is extension of coffee (coffee.cmd) located on \AppData\Roaming\npm. I've just tried again using mingw console and it's working. It's stil weird for me because windows command console is support wilcard, right?

Comment: The best thing I can do is switch into the parent directory and use the directory containing *.coffee files as the target like this: 

    `coffee.cmd -cj scriptall.js js`

where js is the directory name. Seems coffee.cmd is not working well in windows command console to handle wildcard parameter.

Comment: I'd submit that as a bug.

Comment: This is a python script I use to build my coffeescript and haml. Should work in this situation.
http://pastebin.com/wDBw7YC8